# Error in create-react-app - Missing dependencies in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, create-react-app, package.json

I'm using npx create-react-app my-app in CMD (Windows 11) and always get the error "Missing dependencies in package.json". When I try npm start I got "npm ERR! Missing script: "start"".

Tried creating in different folders, uninstalling NodeJS and installing it again with the Node installer and with NVM. Tried installing Yarn. Also tried --use-npm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. Searching through my user folder, I found this file ".npmrc", in C:\Users\User, the only line inside the file was "location=global". I deleted the file and now create-react-app works!

Answer (score 0):

**run this command**

```
npm install
```

or `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`